# jQuery - 3 way toggle switch for Pizza topping

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, toggle

I am new to js/jQuery and if this is a repeat question please forgive me!
I am trying to build pizza ordering website that by clicking on the image button of the toppings places that topping or remove it on the dough image. All toppings must have 3 stages, left side, whole and right side. Then I have to post the selected toppings through ajax/php to the server.

I have tested the ajax/php module and its working. However, I'm stuck on the jQuery part and this is what I have so far:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>topping placement</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    .ButtonClicked {
    background-color:#8C0221;
    }

    .thumb{
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      cursor:pointer;
      }
      .crust{
      float:right;
      padding:100px;
      width:220px;
      height:160px;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:absolute;
      }
      .toppings{
      float:right;
      padding:100px;
      width:220px;
      height:160px;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:absolute;
      display: none;
      opactiy: 0;
      }
      .button-whole{
      background-image: url(../images/button-whole.png);   
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      border: none;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      cursor:pointer;
      }
      .button-l{
      background-image: url(../images/button-l.png);   
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      border: none;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      cursor:pointer;
      }
      .button-r{
      background-image: url(../images/button-r.png);   
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      border: none;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="topping-buttons">
<button id="pep-l" class="button-l" type="submit"></button>
<button id="pep-w" class="button-whole" type="submit"></button>
<button id="pep-r" class="button-r" type="submit"></button>
</div>

<img class="crust" src="../images/crust/thinNcrispy.png" alt="" />
<pepperoni>
<img class="toppings" src="../images/toppings/pepperoni.png" alt="" />
</pepperoni>
<olives_black>
<img class="toppings" src="../images/toppings/olives_black.png" alt="" />
</olives_black>

<script>
    $("#topping-buttons button").click(function() {
        var newval = $("#topping-buttons button").val();
        if (newval == "#pep-l"){
            $( "#pep-l" ).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
            $( "pepperoni img" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
        } else if (newval == "#pep-w"){
            $( "#pep-w" ).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
            $( "pepperoni img" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
        } else if (newval == "#pep-r"){
            $( "#pep-r" ).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
            $( "pepperoni img" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you mean by stuck? What do you get so far?

Comment: I have managed to do the ajax part but cannot get the jquery part to work. I got this jquery to work with 2 buttons (with toggle) but I don't know how to do it with 3 buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things that could be optimized with your JS, but the main problem is that you're setting newval with the value of all three buttons. The quick answer is to use var newval = $(this).val() instead.

The problem there is that you're getting the value of the clicked buttons and buttons inherently don't have a value. You're also comparing against ids.

Following the pattern you're using, something like this would work:

```
var clicked = $(this);

if (clicked.is('#pep-l')) {
// do stuff
} else if (clicked.is('#pep-w')) {
// do stuff
} else {
// do stuff
}
```

That checks if $(this), the clicked button, is the same as the selector you're checking against. Again, there are many things that could be done better - in a less explicit way - but that should function like you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the `id` of clicked button, try below approach:

```
$("#topping-buttons button").click(function() {
    var newval = $(this).prop("id");
    if (newval == "pep-l"){
        alert("pep-l");
    } else if (newval == "pep-w"){
        alert("pep-w");
    } else if (newval == "pep-r"){
        alert("pep-r");
    }
});
```